# jQuery Mobile Change page on click at dynamically created list (data from JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I am new to programming and new some help in editing the js script to get things work.

***Using: jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min and cordova***

I want to achieve this format (4 levels):

> 1. main catagories -> grid button layout
> 2. 1st level sub catagories -> listview (dynamically created using JSON)
> 3. 2nd level sub catagories -> listview (dynamically created using JSON)
> 4. 3rd level details -> basic html display
>      *Some 1st level catagories may not have 2nd level catagories and will jump to display 3rd level details directly

At the moment, I managed to make the main catagories and the 1st level sub catagories display as requested. However, I could not let the 1st level listview to display the 2nd level listview properly.

**JSON data:**

```
var info = [
    //main categories: display as grid buttons
    {"id": 0, "parent": null, "policyName": "0", "policyImg": "img/1.png",}, 
    {"id": 1, "parent": null, "policyName": "1", "policyImg": "img/2.png",},

    //parent: display as 1st level catagories listview
    {"id": 8, "parent": 0, "policyName": "8", }, 
    {"id": 9, "parent": 0, "policyName": "9", }, 
    {"id": 10, "parent": 0, "policyName": "10",}, 

    //parent: display as 2nd level catagories listview
    {"id": 11, "parent": 8, "policyName": "11", "policyURL":"#",}, 
    {"id": 12, "parent": 8, "policyName": "12", "policyURL":"#",}, 
];
```

**jQuery Mobile Script (UPDATED):**

```
//first page
$(document).on("pageinit", "#policy-page", function () {

    var div = "";

    $.each(info, function (i, info) {
        if(info.parent == null) {
            grids = ['a','b','c','d'];
            div += '<div class="ui-block-' + grids[i%4] + '"><div class="ui-bar" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" id="' + i + '" class="info-go ui-link ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" role="button"><img src=" ' + info.policyImg + ' " /><br />' + info.policyName + '</a></div></div>';
        }
    });

    $("#policy-grid").append(div).promise().done(function () {

        $(this).on("click", ".info-go", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#policy-subpage").data("info", info[this.id]);
            $.mobile.changePage("#policy-subpage");
        });
        //add refresh style function
    });

});

//second page
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#policy-subpage", function () {

    var info_sub = $(this).data("info");
    var id = info_sub.id;
    var html = "";

    $.each(info, function (i, info) {
            if (id == info.parent) {
                li =  $('<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '">' + info.policyName + '</a></li>');
                li.on("click", function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        alert($(this).text());
                        $("#policy-subpage2").data("info_sub2", info[this.id]);
                        $.mobile.changePage("#policy-subpage2");
                });

                $("#policy-list").append(li).promise().done(function () {
                    $(this).listview("refresh");
                });
            }
        });[![enter image description here][1]][1]

//third page
// var info_sub2 shows undefined
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#policy-subpage2", function () {

    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    var info_sub2 = $(this).data("info_sub");
    var id2 = info_sub2.id;
    var html = "";

    $.each(info, function (i, info) {
        if (id2 == info.parent) {
            html += '<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '">' + info.policyName + '</a></li>';
        }
    });

    $("#policy-list2").empty();
    if (html != ""){
        $("#policy-list2").append(html);
    }
    else {
        $("#policy-list2").append("<li>No item is found.</li>");
    }
    $("#policy-list2").listview("refresh");

});
```

**HTML (complete):**

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="policy-page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="javascript:window.location.href='index.html';" class="transparentButton" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <a href="javascript:window.location.href='index.html';" class="transparentButton" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <h1>Policy</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-grid-c" id="policy-grid">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--second page --> 
    <div data-role="page" id="policy-subpage">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="transparentButton" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <a href="javascript:window.location.href='index.html';" class="transparentButton" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
             <h1>Policy Subcategories</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="policy-list"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--third page -->  
    <div data-role="page" id="policy-subpage2">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="transparentButton" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <a href="javascript:window.location.href='index.html';" class="transparentButton" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
             <h1>Policy Subcategories2</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="policy-list2"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I did not get any errors under console, but it shows var info_sub2 (at page3) is undefined: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9l905xi13wt0yau/Untitled.png?dl=0 (I do not have enough reputation to upload the screenshot, hence a link)

when I went through the codes step by step. So, I guess the on click function in my 2nd page should contains some errors. However, I could not solve it.

Can someone kindly go through my mistakes and give me some suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you add the events BEFORE you add the data.

You need to add the .on("click") in the same loop where you create the li elements (use the code more as en example):

```
if (id == info.parent) {
        var li =  $('<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '">' + info.policyName + '</a></li>');
        li.on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert($(this).text());
                $("#policy-subpage2").data("info_sub2", info[this.id]);
                $.mobile.changePage("#policy-subpage2");
        });

        $("#policy-list").append(li).promise().done(function () {
            $(this).listview("refresh");
        });
    }
```

As for the last part, you could restructure the code there as well:

```
// the li elements
var lis = [];

$.each(info, function (i, info) {
    if (id2 === info.parent) {
        var li = $('<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '">' + info.policyName + '</a></li>');
        li.on("click", function(){ alert("li: " + $(this.attr("id")); });
        list.push(li); // add to array
    }
});

// default no items

$("#policy-list2").empty();
if (lis.length === 0){
    $("#policy-list2").append("<li>No item is found.</li>");
}
else {
    // add the list
    $.each(lis, function(){
        $("#policy-list2").append(this);
    });
}
```

Its always better to have the events directly on the elements you add instead of using global events (they are way slower)

slow:

```
   $(document).on("click", "li")...
```

fast:

```
    $("li").on("click")...
```

The reason why the first is slower, is that on any click within the document, jquery will go through the list of events and try each out if it fits the rule. (so if you have 100 events, jquery will iterate over all 100 everytime you click anywhere on the page and check if it matches).

on the other hand, when you bind the function directly on the element, the browser handles the resolution much more efficient internally and only calls the javascript if it is bound.

On click events this does not feel like much, but when you try the same thing with move events like mouse-over or mouse-out, you will quickly notice a lag.

Comment: thanks for replying :) I did put it after I created the <li> elements under 2nd page, using .append() only .on("click") :/ The alert did shows up after I pressed the <li> and the url changed from #policy-subpage to #policy-subpage2. However the 3rd page contents did not refresh and load thou.

Comment: I guessed you mean like this? I amended my codes for the 2nd page :) based on alert my onclick did detected the right <li> already. However, now there is a new problem (besides id2 still undefined I dont know why) -- my list will have unorganized repetition, it displayed 6 <li> instead of 3, eg: id= 8,8,9,8,9,10. Any suggestion on where else I am wrong at?

Comment: @Joysofyz I updated the description with my usual approach, hope it helps

Comment: Hi again! Thanks for the changes on the codes :> But there is one more error at page 3 :( I am not sure why the id=undefined when the alert pop up displays the 1st li content thou? has attached a link to view the debugging picture. Do help if can!! :D appreciate it very much!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I managed to solve the undefined parts by modifying the value I passed down :D

Answer (score 0):

Oh I solve it!

Just change the 2nd page script to below for it to work:

```
//second page
        $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#policy-subpage", function () {

            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var li = "";

            $.each(info, function (i, info) {
                if (id == info.parent) {
                    li =  $('<li id="' + info.id + '"><a href="#">' + info.policyName + '</a></li>');
                    li.on("click", function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            alert(this.id);
                            $("#policy-subpage2").data("id", this.id);
                            $.mobile.changePage("#policy-subpage2");
                    });

                    $("#policy-list").append(li).promise().done(function () {
                        $(this).listview("refresh");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```